# JHipster - Separate back-end and front-ends, how to glue together

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

my aim is to have one back-end, but some front-ends.

Creating separate back-end and front-end with JHipster using:

```
jhipster --skip-client

jhipster --skip-server --db="mssql" --auth"jwt"
```

When the back-end ist created, navigating into the project folder and executing:

```
mvn
```

and it will run at http://locahost:8080

When the front-end is created, navigating into the project folder and executing:

```
ng serve
```

and it will run at http://localhost:4200

(The front-end right now is not working, see [JHipster - Separate front-end, starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638213/jhipster-separate-front-end-starting))

I'm wondering on which parts of the back-end and front-end I have to develop/configure after creation so it works?

I assume, that when creating the entities with JDL:

```
jhipster import-jdl <JDL file>.jh
```

this has to be done in the project folder of the back-end and also in the project folder of the front-end?

In the front-end I believe just pointing to the REST service running at http://localhost:8080 is enough?

What about the authentication? Is this already configured correctly (front-end creation with command at the top) so that on this no need to take care?

Cheers

Comment: I don't know but if some options are missing, just copy them from server .yo-rc.json into client .yo-rc.json